# How to change payload option '--data' in Postman request

Tags: curl, postman

I need to retrieve data from external system. It successfully accept request like this:

```
curl --data "authKey=<key>" http://app.arnica.pro/primehill/primeHillApi/entryPoint/method/getClients
```

But when I try to make this request in Postman it fails.

I think that it happens because Postman send payload with other option. For example, if i choose option `x-www-form-urlencoded`, and then go to code --> cURL I got this:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://app.arnica.pro/primehill/primeHillApi/entryPoint/method/getClients' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--header 'Cookie: PHPSESSID=hp43k9rog7vtgu6jk9hlbbnlq5' \
--data-urlencode 'authKey=<key>'
```

So, payload option is `--data-urlencode` instead of just `--data` now.

I've tried to import cURL request that works, but Postman change opton `--data-urlencode` and request failed.

Is there in Postman any options to change it to `--data` manualy?

**UPD:** screenshots of results with different options:

- [raw data (fail)](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/rIk7KrF6beGX2-v9v2uiVv281JhCmNtDmzUy1CszDZMFNexAofEvYQZXdE1QxZcAkxud6renIUT3C1rJVi1rokl7gPiPGoZPYSj20I_vVvIyZRvvZG1bpapzzXFlr963ZotTuaEp)
- [form (fail)](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/5ix9osNGLv__IPudNseXyQr_amKrGypOoyfLPMqRD6TGWvUe-zkxQIFfK5epTdDGIU9Y-ZCtbGfvX0Sdah3HVB_vnvX-2KEhnSqptj40F960Su4Op-ooZg0IVl3t_RCo9CksqZs6)
- [x-www-form-urlencoded (fail)](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/xamyApmqh7fyy34EFEoZ7ARh6X2mAHrPuD2UxZ5ouxvH7LUovu3BEmNr3vsizsUn5yQCy0El-Vji78Trjba_BwtV5b5-x9I6hNdVFPH0bi38Qwxua6bYFPXJGYUKFiVQkMLh7MHu)
- [not-Postman with `--data` option (success)](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/GqeigHGIFB-hRh7mmYR1tMcy73hzM4G0DRddrX8FcKtglFMvt30aG6VvzMRoIlwApojWysu-DNtIRRVDyyVeox8qbN52frgHzjjTeY06j6dX7NDywyjHiY6yvWB8T1MuRkz7bJvl)

**UPD2:** `lucasnguyen17` was right. Problem was in http/https. For some reason reqbin.com changed http to https. And that is why there are were successful request.

Option indeed has no influence on result!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

I did some tests with postman-echo, and here is the things:

1. `--data` and `--data-urlencode` produces the same result.

[image]

2. Use option `x-www-form-urlencoded`, same result.

[image]

I think you could try option `--data-urlencode` on your Curl tool to confirm it is the problem.

Comment: I've tried this and every other option of `Body`.

Postman turn raw body to cURL option `--data-raw`

Comment: Can you update the error you got when using postman?

Comment: Well it is successful request with error from external system `"error": "authKey должен быть указан"` (which in english means "There are should be authKey")

Comment: I've updated initial description and add screens of results with different options

Comment: You were right. Problem was in http/https. For some reason reqbin.com changed http to https. And that is why there are were successful request. 

Option indeed has no influence on result. Thank You!